# Showing a renormalization result from an introductory paper on Feynman integrals

Tags: calculus, analysis, mathematical-physics, regularization

I am reading [a paper on Feynman integrals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1855), where the author states that from the following equation (96),
$$Z_g=1-\frac12\beta_0\frac{g_R^2}{(4\pi)^2}+O(g_R^4),$$
we obtain the equation (99)
$$Z_g^{-1}\mu\frac{d}{d\mu}Z_g=\beta_0\frac{g_R^2}{(4\pi)^2}+O(g_R^4).$$ Somehow I cannot seem to derive this result. Note that $\beta_0$ is a constant here and $g_R$ is being shown to depend on $\mu$. Previously, it was shown that the equation (98) holds:
$$\mu\frac{d}{d\mu}g_R=-\epsilon g_R-(Z_g^{-1}\mu\frac{d}{d\mu}Z_g)g_R$$ and we are taking the limit as $\epsilon\to0$ (it's the dimensional regularization parameter). Can I obtain equation (99) from these two results or am I missing something?

Comment: The paper's exposition could do with being clearer, but here's my read. You know $\ln Z_g\sim-\tfrac12\beta_0\frac{g_R^2}{(4\pi)^2}$, and want to prove $\frac{d\ln Z_g}{d\ln\mu}$ is $-2$ times this, i.e. $\ln Z_g\propto\mu^{-2}$. This is equivalent to $g_R\propto\mu^{-1}$. Since $\frac{d\ln g_R}{d\ln\mu}=-\frac{d\ln Z_g}{d\ln\mu}\implies g_R\propto Z_g^{-1}$ as $\epsilon\to0$, you just need $Z_g\propto\mu$.